# Running `expo start` fails with ENOENT error just after installing expo-cli on windows 10

Tags: react-native, windows-10, expo

I'm on Windows 10 Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299. I'm using Powershell. I just used `yarn global add expo-cli` to install [expo](https://expo.io/), then I ran `expo init my-app` then `cd my-app` and `expo start`, but the build is failing. Here's the error image and text:

[image]

```
[23:11:49] Starting project at C:\projects\my-app
[23:11:58] Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
[23:11:58] Metro Bundler ready.
[23:12:00] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[23:12:00] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Any ideas? Or even suggestions on another place where I can post this issue since it's failing out of the box. All help appreciated.

Comment: You should post it on the https://forums.expo.io/ or their github

Answer (score 1):

For windows:-
add environment variable in 
set Path - C:\Windows\System32\
after setting path. restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added `C:\Windows\System32\`

See the Picture below:

[image]